# Filling in a pandas column based on existing number of strings

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, filter

I have a pandas data-frame that looks like this:

```
ID     Hobbby    Name
1      Travel    Kevin
2      Photo     Andrew
3      Travel    Kevin
4      Cars      NaN
5      Photo     Andrew
6      Football  NaN
.............. 1303 rows.
```

The number of Names filled in might be large then 2 as well. I would like to end up the entire Names column filled n equally into the names ( or+1 in the case of even number of rows). I already store into  a variable number of names the total number of names. In the above case it's 2. I tried filtering and counting by each name but I don't know how to make this when the number of name is dynamic.
Expected Dataframe:

```
 ID     Hobbby    Name
1      Travel    Kevin
2      Photo     Andrew
3      Travel    Kevin
4      Cars      Kevin
5      Photo     Andrew
6      Football  Andrew
```

I tried: replace NaN with 0 in Column Name using fillna. Filter the column and end up with a dataframe that has only the na fields and afterwards len(df) to get the number of nan and from here created 2 databases each containing half of the df. Bu I think this approach is completely wrong as I do not always have 2 Names. There could be2,3,4 etc. ( this is given by a dictionary)

Any help highly appreciated

Thanks.

Comment: can you post the code you have tried and the output you are expecting?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell but I think you need `ffill`

```
df['Name'] = df['Name'].ffill()
```